# How can I add a .pkpass file to Wallet?

Tags: iphone, ios, wallet

I have a .pkpass file which contains the boarding card for my next flight. Can I add it to iOS Wallet or is it not possible to add a .pkpass file? In case it is possible, how can I do it?

I am using iOS 9.2.1 in an iPhone 4S

Comment: You could probably use iExplorer to find the place where your pkpasses are stored, then drop the file in that folder...

Comment: Hey pal, maybe it's time to `accept` one of the answers (you know, help the guy who helped you).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the `.pkpass` file downloaded to a computer. This worked for me:

1. send yourself an email with the `.pkpass` file attached
2. open the email on the iphone
3. tap the attachment
4. 'Add' it to your wallet

Comment: It didn't work with the Gmail app. Had to use Apple's own Mail app.

Comment: Odd, I used the gmail app 2 months ago. Was using iOS 11 on an iPhone 7. But glad you found something that worked!

Comment: It worked for me with the latest Gmail iPhone app. iOS 15.

Comment: works on ios15 in 2022 perfectly

Answer (score 12):

If you have an Apple computer, you could also use airdrop. The card or pass will be added to your wallet automatically.

Comment: Can confirm it just worked. Had a .pkpass file for my flight. I tried the top voted solution first (shared a file on my messenger app, and tried to open), but the phone didn't recognize it. Tried putting it into Files - still no luck. Finally airdropped it to my iPhone from my Mac and that instantly added it to my wallet. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

One thing that will block you from being able to add a `.pkpass` file to your Apple Wallet is the format of that file. I purchased a movie ticket that came with `.pkpass` file via email that included spaces in it so my phone was unable to recognize it (e.g., `file name.pkpass`).

To fix my issue I AirDrop'd it to my laptop, reformatted the file (e.g., `file_name.pkpass`), and sent it pack to my iPhone. It was instantly able to recognize it as valid format, and I successfully added it to my Apple Wallet.

Hopefully this will help future searches on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Wallet on your iPhone open up the boarding pass provided from airline. At the top right hand corner of phone shows Add - tap this and it should automatically add to your Wallet. Have just done this with Boarding Passes received from Thomson. Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, which is more of a workaround, while sending the `.pkpass` file(s) via email or AirDrop is probably easier: in macOS you can host the directory containing your `.pkpass` file(s) on the local network, either using some Terminal shenanigans, possibly with something like [`curldrop`](https://github.com/kennell/curldrop), or with apps like The Iconfactory's [**WorldWideWeb**](https://apps.apple.com/app/id1621370168). Then, on i[Pad]OS, just open the local network URL in Safari, tap to download, and the OS will immediately ask to add it to your **Wallet** app.